# What encoding type does VB6 use to encode forms, classes and modules?

Tags: vb6

I am writing a C# script that instruments some VB6 code.

I need to output the generated code using the same encoding as VB6 to avoid losing character data. Right now it keeps changing Latin characters, like é, to null characters.

Notepad++ guesses that VB6 files are ANSCII by default, but since they don't have a BOM that's just an educated guess. I have tried encoding with ANSCII and it still loses character data.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try windows-1252 (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049272/what-is-the-default-vb6-charset and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

Comment: If windows-1252 is not it try ISO-88591. I found that text files that were being output from SQL data by our code were encoded this way where we had not specified any file encoding. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1

Comment: Interesting. I thought this would be answered clearly by the documentation, but [all I can find in the "Form Structures" chapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa241723%28v=vs.60%29) says ASCII. But clearly that can't be right if the source has non-ASCII characters in it. My *guess* would be that it's in the system's default ANSI code page, as would be typical for pre-Unicode applications, but I'd love to find a citation for that.

Comment: windows-1252 did the trick

Comment: I opened an FRM in Notepad++ and it says UTF-8. That was a surprise...

Answer (score 2):

After testing this encoding as windows-1252 preserves the characters.

Comment: That is not precise. The compiler uses ACP so for example I'm able to compile cyrillic texts in my executables using Windows-1251 for system codepage for non-unicode applications here.